# AIX - creating and mounting a FS

Tags: unix, filesystems, aix, mount, mount-point

I create a FS on AIX6 easily with 3 commands. The procedure that i follow is:

```
1- mklv ..........

2- crfs (with -m mountpoint) ........

3- mount .......
```

But when i have tried the same procedure on AIX7, i got the following error:

**mount: 0506-324 Cannot mount DEVICENAME on MOUNTPOINT. A file or directory in the path name does not exist.**

I have to use **mkdir** command to create the mountpoint. Am i missing sth or is it a new feature (limitation) for AIX7? Maybe its because of an OS setting?

Comment: note that the tag aix has only 152 followers here on S.O.  I have seen better AIX answers in the unix group on ITToolbox.com. You have to register and find the group (+join group to post question), but you're more likely to get help there. Also ibm has AIX specific support forums. You'd do well to dig into them too. Good luck.

Comment: thanks @shellter, i have added the "unix" tag.

Comment: your problem is very AIX specific, but good luck.

Comment: AND, given that this is about managing system resources, you'll get a whole different group of people looking at your problem if you use the `flag` link at the bottom and ask the moderator to move your Q to the stackexchange related site for sysadmins (not just (*nix)  ... http://serverfault.com/ . Good luck.

Comment: I would read the manual of mount(1). (To me, the 'problematic' new behaviour seems to be more natural.)